# Explain 'Idle Time' in Tensorboard (TF 2)

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I am profiling using TensorBoard the new(ish) profiling tools.  One option in"Tensorflow_stats" is a prompt to include IDLE time or not:

[image: Tensorboard showing IDLE option]

When I Yes, Enable, IDLE time jumps to the top of the "Top Operations" which lists those times which are slowest.  However,**the time given is much bigger than wall time measured on a watch**.  What is included and how is this "IDLE" time determined?